# Javascript behaviour reuse: What side effects will this approach have?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-oriented

I'm trying to understand pure prototype-based JavaScript and one specific thing I'm struggling with is reuse (inheritance).

For my project I landed this way of creating objects that can be reused.

```
// very generic prototype
var Apparatus = (function(){
    var self = Object.create({});
    self.state = false;
    self.on = function() { this.state = true; };
    return self;
})();

// more specific prototype
var Radio = (function(){
    var self = Object.create(Apparatus);
    self.frequency = 0;
    self.setFrequency = function(f) { this.frequency = f; }
    self.getFrequency = function() { return this.frequency; } 
    return self;
})();
```

I then want to "instantiate"/copy the Radio object, creating two different radios.

```
var kitchenRadio = Object.create(Radio);
kitchenRadio.state = false;
kitchenRadio.on();

var carRadio = Object.create(Radio);
carRadio.state = false;

console.log(kitchenRadio.state, carRadio.state);
// true false
```

This works, but will it continue to? Can anyone predict any unwanted outcomes?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is unwanted, but `Radio.on()` will set `kitchenRadio.state` to `true`.

Comment: So I have to specifically create state properties in both kitchenRadio and carRadio to avoid that. Can I remedy this without changing the approach extensively?

Comment: I guess the point is that functions should be inherited, but not properties such as `state`. All radios are turned on in a common way, but each radio has its own state. So, each eventual instance would have its own properties, whereas the functions are inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @pimvdb said, remove state and this works well.

```
// very generic prototype
var Apparatus = (function(){
    var self = Object.create({});
    self.on = function() { this.state = true; };
    return self;
})();

// more specific prototype
var Radio = (function(){
    var self = Object.create(Apparatus);
    self.setFrequency = function(f) { this.frequency = f; }
    self.getFrequency = function() { return this.frequency; } 
    return self;
})();
```

I then use `Object.create(Object, params)` to instantiate it.